# Is there an algebraic solution to $\log_{\sqrt2}{\left(x\right)} = (\sqrt2)^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, closed-form, inverse-function, lambert-w

I’m trying to solve
$$\log_{\sqrt2}{\left(x\right)} = (\sqrt2)^x$$

My next step is
$$\ln{x}= (\sqrt2)^x\ \cdot\ \ln\sqrt2$$

**EDIT:**
I’m only up to high school math.

Comment: Can you see the image

Comment: Hi again, 1) Please type in your problem using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 2) Could you tell us what you have tried? Where this problem comes from? etc. This will increase the reception of your post and prevent it from being closed or deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested edit, I’ve not used mathjax before and was struggling. I was plotting the inverse functions for log and exponent which intersect at y=x for base sqrt2 at x=2 and x=4. So I wondered if we could arrive at those solutions algebraically.

Comment: @coffeemath The comment was made when there was no mathjax formatting so I was asking for clarification since it was unclear.

Comment: @coffeemath ?? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nyprd90gbp

Comment: @ReGuess Sorry, had wrong function. deleted.

Comment: Do you know basic calculus? You could compute the minima of $f(x)=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}-x$ and with a little bit of guesswork, apply intermediate value theorem to find the solution(s)

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564127/all-real-and-closed-form-roots-of-log-2x-frac-2x-1x for a similar question

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(\sqrt2)^x=(e^{\ln\sqrt2})^x = e^{x\ln\sqrt2}$, and $\ln\sqrt2=\ln{(2^{1/2})}=\frac12\ln2$

That said, it may be easier to go back a step and use 2 as our base instead of $e$:

Starting with $\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)=(\sqrt{2})^{x}$, on the left-hand side we have

$$\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)=\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{\log_{2}(\sqrt2)}=\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{1/2}= 2 \log_{2}(x)=\log_{2}(x^2)$$

(I've introduced an extraneous solution in that last step, but if we assume $x>0$ we'll be fine.)

And on the right-hand side we have $(\sqrt{2})^{x}=(2^{1/2})^x=2^{\ x/2}$, so

$$\log_{2}(x^2)=2^{\ x/2}\Rightarrow x^2 = 2^{2^{(x/2)}}\Rightarrow x = \sqrt{2^{2^{(x/2)}}}=(2^{2^{(x/2)}})^{1/2}$$

... and at this point I'm stumped. I know the answer has to do with the fact that $2^2=2\cdot 2=2+2=4$, but my closest attempt at getting WolframAlpha to solve it by algebraic manipulations has resulted in expressions which involve the Lambert W function but somehow evaluate to 2 and 4.

Maybe it might be useful to note that to note is that $f(x)=\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)$  and $g(x)=(\sqrt{2})^{x}$ are inverse functions of each other, so when $f(x)=g(x)$, then they are both equal to $x$. From there the path seems to be through the Lambert W function, which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

I don't feel like this is an answer yet, but I want to post my work so far in case it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed working! I’m only up to high school math so I haven’t learned the Lambert W function yet. My tutor suggested trying to differentiate the f(x) and g(x) and equate that to 1 (where they intersect with y=x as inverse functions). I haven’t been able to go anywhere with it yet.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^x$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^x$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}-\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^x=0\tag{1}$$
$F(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}-\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^x$:
$$F(x)=0$$

We see from (1), your equation is an algebraic equation in dependence of two algebraically independent monomials ($\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}$, $\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^x$). With help of the main theorem in [Ritt 1925], that is also proved in [Risch 1979], we can conclude that  the [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) $F$ doesn't have a [partial inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that is an elementary function. Therefore, the equation cannot be *rearranged* for $x$ by applying only elementary functions/operations we can read from the equation.

[[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

**a)**

Because the real functions $f$ and $g$ are the inverses of each other, as ReGuess writes in his answer, the problem in the reals can be splitted into a simpler problem: it's enough to solve one of the following two equations. The graphs of $f$ and $g$ together with the graph of the identity function show this for the reals.

$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}=x$$
$$\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^x=x$$

Each of these equations can be solved by [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), as ReGuess correctly writes. Each of the equations has the real solutions $2$ and $4$.

**b)**

an extra for the interested reader:

Your equation can be solved in terms of generalized hyper-Lambert (see the references below):

$$\frac{2\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)x}$$
$$\frac{2\ln(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}ln(2)x}}{\ln(2)}=1$$
$$\ln(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)x}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$$
$x=e^t$:
$\forall k_1\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$te^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)e^t}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+2k_1\pi i$$
$$G(-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2);t)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+2k_1\pi i$$
$$t=HW(-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2);\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+2k_1\pi i)$$
$\forall k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$x=\ln(HW(-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2);\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+2k_1\pi i))+2k_2\pi i$$

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Comment: Thank you very much! When I get to the stage in my study where I learn about the Lambert function I’ll be sure to reference your explanation, might take me a few years but I’ll get there, thank you again!

Comment: @NimnaDeSilva My personal advice for your future: You will know more than others if you always remember what I said about Ritt's theorem. And you'll be more easily guided to the infinite series appropriate for the math problem at hand if you try to look for closed-form solutions first.

Answer (score 2):

$\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)$ is concave down. $\sqrt{2}^x$ is concave up. Therefore there are at most two solutions.

After writing these more "nicely" as $2\log_2(x)$ and $2^{x/2}$, we can "see" that $2$ and $4$ are solutions, by luck of these particular numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The equation as presented takes the form
$$ 2 \, \ln x = 2^{x/2} \, \ln 2. $$
It is fairly clear that if $x = 2$ then $ 2 \, \ln 2 = 2 \, \ln 2$ which is a solution to the equation. The next solution should be an even integer value, like $x = 4$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it can only be solved by inspection?

Comment: @NimnaDeSilva    In this case it seems easier to "solve" by inspection. One can also plot the graphs of $\ln(x^2)$, which is $2 \, \ln x$, verses $\ln 2 \, 2^{x/2}$ which it will be shown that the two points of intersection are $x \in \{ 2, 4 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest:

$$\log_{\sqrt 2}(x) = (\sqrt{2})^x$$
$$\implies {\sqrt{2}}^{\log_{\sqrt 2}(x)} = {\sqrt{2}}^{(\sqrt{2})^x}$$
$$\implies x = {\sqrt{2}}^{(\sqrt{2})^x}$$
$$\implies  x = 2^{\frac{1}{2} \times 2^{\frac{x}{2}}}.$$

The LHS is linear, whereas the RHS is doubly exponential and convex [and rapidly increasing in $x$]. There is no nice way in general to solve this, but by inspection $x=2$ and $x=4$ works [as already noted in the previous answer].