# All real and closed-form roots of $\log_2x=\frac {2^{x-1}}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation, lambert-w

> What are the closed-form roots of
> $$\log_2x=\frac {2^{x-1}}{x}$$
> ?

My attempts:

Closed-form means, I assume that the Lambert W function can work.

I know that, at least $x>0$.

Wolfram Alpha gives the result $x=2, x=4$. But how? Honestly, I don't like this method: We will prove that $x=2,x=4$ are only solutions. I think, this is not a good way.

I want to know that, where do roots come from? What is the closed form?

I did some manipulations.

$$x=2^{\frac {2^{x-1}}{x}}$$

$$x^x=2^{2^{x-1}}$$

But, nothing comes from here.

Then, I tried the substitution $x=2^t$, so we have

$$t=\frac{2^{2^t-1}}{{2^t}}$$

$$t2^t=2^{2^{t-1}-1}$$

This seems more reasonable:

Because, $f(t)=t2^t$ looks like the well-known form $f(x)=xe^x$,which is solvable with Lambert W function. But, I understand that RHS is not a constant. That was a just observation. I am wondering, can Lambert-W solve the given equation?

I couldn't proceed anymore.

Comment: Would you like a hint or a solution?

Comment: @Ajay The full solution is always best, I think

Comment: See [this solution to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553837/is-there-an-algebraic-solution-to-log-sqrt2-leftx-right-sqrt2x/4561521#4561521).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations are equivalent to
$$2x\log_2(x)=2^x$$
$$x^2\log_2(x^2)=x2^x$$
$$x^2\ln(x^2)=\ln(2)xe^{\ln(2)x}$$

Apply $W$ to each side:
$$\ln(x^2)=\ln(2)x$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac12\right)$$

Apply $W$ to each side:
$$\ln(1/x)=W\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac12\right)\right)$$

Can you take it from here? Following the $W_0$ branch leads you to $2$. Following the $W_{-1}$ branch leads you to $4$.